# Pass string array as parameter in SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand, sqlcommandbuilder

In my application written in C# , I am writing a SQL query. Following is the query

```
SELECT [Resource No_] where [Resource No_] In (@resources)
```

`@resources` is user input parameters having one or more that one strings.

My query is failing **without showing an error**

According to me, query is failing because in `@resources` parameter following is being passed

```
"'123,'124','125'"
```

(there are **2 inverted commas in the beginning and at the end** and that is failing my query).

`[Resource No_]` is of type `NVARCHAR` in the database.

After Googling, I have found some help on this topic but all are applicable when `[Resource No_]`  is of type `Integer`

Comment: Show us how you create this query.

Comment: creating a dynamics string in not possible because I don't know the number of parameters passed by user.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead :: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (SELECT [Resource No_] where [Resource No_] In (@resources) , conn)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/2864740

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't agree with the selected answer (or many of the tricky answers) for the "duplicate question", [here is an answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/2864740) which shows an approach very similar with my following recommendation.

(I've voted to close this question as a duplicate, because there *are* such answers, even if buried.)

---

Only one *SQL value* can be bound to any given placeholder.

While there ways to send all the data as "one value", I'd recommend creating the *placeholders* dynamically: it's simple, clean, and will work reliably in most cases.

Consider this:

```
ICollection<string> resources = GetResources();

if (!resources.Any()) {
    // "[Resource No_] IN ()" doesn't make sense
    throw new Exception("Whoops, have to use different query!");
}

// If there is 1 resource, the result would be "@res0" ..
// If there were 3 resources, the result would be "@res0,@res1,@res2" .. etc
var resourceParams = string.Join(",",
    resources.Select((r, i) => "@res" + i));

// This is NOT vulnerable to classic SQL Injection because resourceParams
// does NOT contain user data; only the parameter names.
// However, a large number of items in resources could result in degenerate
// or "too many parameter" queries so limit guards should be used.
var sql = string.Format("SELECT [Resource No_] where [Resource No_] In ({0})",
    resourceParams);

var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql;

// Assign values to placeholders, using the same naming scheme.
// Parameters prevent SQL Injection (accidental or malicious).
int i = 0;
foreach (var r in resources) {
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@res" + i, r);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: This is not the question. Your answer is how to create a new SQL statement; not nice when you have a few thousand entries.

Comment: @fcm I don't think you understand the answer, this is about how you parameterise the query when you have an unknown number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use a user defined table type to accept your parameter, then a JOIN clause in your select to limit the results set. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f466c93-43cd-436d-8a7c-e458feae71a0/how-to-use-user-defined-table-types

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
resources.Aggregate(r1, r2 => r1 + "', '" + r2 + "'")
```

and pass the list in one string.